# Defining global layout with react-native-navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to wrap my entire navigation stuff inside the following boilerplate:

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
    <View>
        <View>
            <Navbar />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bodyWrapper}>
            // Navigation setup here
        </View>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Basically this is my routing setup:

```
Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
    topBar: {
        visible: false,
        drawBehind: true
    }
})

Navigation.registerComponent("myapp.Home", () => Home)

Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
        stack: {
            children: [{
                component: {
                    name: 'myapp.Home'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: You could put all that code in the first snippet in a component called e.g. `Layout` and render the `children` prop, and use that for every route in your app. There will be a bit of duplicated code having `Layout` as the top component in every route component, but that might be alright.

Comment: @Tholle That's a nice approach. But yeah the code duplication :(